# nginx-ingress: Too many redirects when force-ssl is enabled

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kops, kubernetes-ingress

I am setting up my first ingress in kubernetes using nginx-ingress. I set up the `ingress-nginx` load balancer service like so:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "ingress-nginx",
    "namespace": "...",
    "labels": {
      "k8s-addon": "ingress-nginx.addons.k8s.io"
    },
    "annotations": {     
      "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol": "tcp",
      "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol": "*",
      "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert": "arn....",
      "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports": "443"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "http",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": "http",
        "nodePort": 30591
      },
      {
        "name": "https",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 443,
        "targetPort": "http",
        "nodePort": 32564
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "app": "ingress-nginx"
    },
    "clusterIP": "...",
    "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "sessionAffinity": "None",
    "externalTrafficPolicy": "Cluster"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {
      "ingress": [
        {
          "hostname": "blablala.elb.amazonaws.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how the `https` port has its `targetPort` property pointing to port 80 (http) in order to terminate ssl at the load balancer.

My ingress looks something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: something
  namespace: ...
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: www.exapmle.com
      http:
        paths:
         - path: /
           backend:
            serviceName: some-service
            servicePort: 2100
```

Now when I navigate to the url I get a `Too many redirects error`. Something that is confusing me is that when I add the following header "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" I get the expected response (`curl https://www.example.com -v -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"`).

Any ideas how I can resolve the issue?

P.S. this works just fine with `ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"` and it doesn't seem that there are any extraneous redirects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a known issue with the `annotation` for SSL-redirection in combination with proxy-protocol and termination of SSL connections on ELB.

Question about it was published on [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/71) and here is a [fix](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/71#issuecomment-369622493) from that thread:

1. You should create a custom ConfigMap for an Nginx-Ingress instead of using `force-ssl-redirect` annotation like the following:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ConfigMap
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: ingress-nginx
     name: nginx-ingress-configuration
     namespace: <ingress-namespace>
   data:
     ssl-redirect: "false"
     hsts: "true"
     server-tokens: "false"
     http-snippet: |
       server {
         listen 8080 proxy_protocol;
         server_tokens off;
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
       }
   ```

   That configuration will create an additional listener with a simple redirection to https.
2. Then, apply that ConfigMap to your ingress-controller, add `NodePort` 8080 to its container definition and to the Service.
3. Now, you can point the port 80 of your ELB to port 8080 of the Service.

With that additional listener, it will work.

Comment: Why listen 8000 and NodePort 8080?

Comment: Mistype. Thanks, I set 8080 in the config.

Comment: About step 2: Does it have to be a `NodePort`? Can I have a `ClusterIP` instead?

Comment: Depends of your configuration, actually. The point is to make it forward requests from clients to that port from `http` port. That is just a small redirection server, which will forward client from `http://_anything_` to `https://the_same_anything_`. Nothing more.

Comment: How can we do this on ingress level, for specific ones only. Instead of configmap for the whole ingress controller???

Comment: how does one apply this with helm install using the public helm chart?

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 16):

Adding another cause for the `Too many redirects error`.

While working with *ingress-nginx* as an ingress controller in front of some k8s services.

**One of the services** (ArgoCD in my case) **handled TLS termination by itself and always redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS**.

**The problem is that the nginx ingress controller also handled TLS termination** and communicates with the backend service with HTTP then the result is that the ArgoCD's server always responding with a redirects to HTTPS which is the cause for the multiple redirects.

Any attempts to pass relevant values to the ingress **annotations below will not help**:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false/true
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"/"HTTPS"
```

**The solution was to ensure that the service doesn't handle TLS by passing `--insecure` flag to the argocd-server deployment**:

spec:

```
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: argocd-server
        command:
        - argocd-server
        - --repo-server
        - argocd-repo-server:8081
        - --insecure # <-- Here
```

Comment: Commented on 12/23/2021. Nothing is working but yours. Thank you soooo much

Comment: thanks m8, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I'm using ArgoCD as well, which needs ssl-passthrough configured, as per docs: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/#option-1-ssl-passthrough

Comment: the official documentation of argocd,     # If you encounter a redirect loop or are getting a 307 response code
    # then you need to force the nginx ingress to connect to the backend using HTTPS.
    #
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"

Answer (score 5):

I had to add these annotations to make it work without changing the ingress-controller:

```
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-ingress-internal # <- AWS NLB
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
```

Comment: best answer as per my env

Comment: This works fine, and best suits for all environments

Comment: doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that worked for my environment (k8s v1.16.15, rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.32.0-rancher1):

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
```

This worked with the force-ssl-redirect on the ingress of the application. It seems that the ingress-controller does not use the X-Forwarded-Proto header from the ELB out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this annotation:
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS`

fixed it for me. full example here: https://github.com/argoproj/argoproj-deployments/blob/master/argo-workflows/resources/argo-server-ingress.yaml

Comment: This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issues in **Keycloak** setup via helm chart as well. The SSL termination is done on ELB so to fix it . I made the following changes in helm values.

```
ingress:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
```

This helped me fixed it.